# UIAppearance with UITableViewCell selectedBackgroundView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiappearance

In the header for `UITableViewCell`, `selectedBackgroundView` and `backgroundColor` are not labelled as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, however the following code works:

```
UITableViewCell *cellAppearance = [UITableViewCell appearance];
cellAppearance.backgroundColor = kCellBackgroundColor;

UIView *selectedView = [UIView new];
selectedView.backgroundColor = kMainPrimaryColor;
cellAppearance.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
```

The background colors of my cells and the selected animation are modified for all of my tables. Any ideas why this works? I would like to know if properties on other objects work as well even when not marked as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.